# What is the name for an ODE with an integral as a side condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, probability-distributions, problem-solving

**My question:** I have to find a function $y: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ fulfilling $$y^\prime(t) = f(t, y(t)),\ \int_{-\infty}^\infty y(t) dt = c$$  with a given $c \in \mathbb R$. What is the name of this kind of problem in the theory of ordinary differential equations? Can you suggest some literature about this topic (especially how one can numerically solve such a problem)?

I know [initial value problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem) and [boundary value problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_value_problem). Unfortunately I have not heard about problems in ODE where one has an integral as a side condition...

**Reason for my question:** Imagine on can prove for the density $\phi$ of a random variable, that $\phi^\prime(t) = f(t, \phi(t))$. In order to find $\phi(t)$ one has to solve $$\phi^\prime(t) = f(t, \phi(t)),\ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(t) dt = 1$$

Comment: Maybe you mean the density of a random variable, not distribution. But OK :)

Comment: @Martingalo: Thanks! ;-)

Comment: Can't you just find a general solution of the ODE which depends on a generic constant and then impose the integral condition in order to find the right constant? For instance $y'(t) = -y(t)$, $t>0$ has general solution $y(t) = Ce^{-t}$ and the constant you want is: $C\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t} dt =1$. So $C=1$ and $y(t)$ is the density of an exponential r.v.

Comment: @Martingalo: I know this kind of solution. I am interested in cases where the ODE cannot be solved analytically and I want to find numerical methods to solve such an ODE...

Comment: Do you have access to Journals? look at this paper:
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042702003710

Comment: @Martingalo: Thanks a lot! ;-) Please write a short answer with the link to the article so that I can accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this article: :) They call it "ODE with integral boundary conditions"

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042702003710